# How long is this string, really?

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, balanced-string

In most programming languages, the string `Hello, World!` can be represented as `"Hello, World!"`. But if you want to represent `"Hello, World!"` you need to escape the double quotes with backslashes for `"\"Hello, World!\""`, and to represent *that* you also need to escape the backslashes resulting in `"\"\\\"Hello, World!\\\"\""`.

Your challenge is to, given a printable ASCII string that's been escaped multiple times (such as `"\"\\\"Hello, World!\\\"\""`, find how many characters it is when fully unescaped. Specifically, you should remove a single pair of enclosing `"` and replace `\\` with `\` and `\"` with `"`, until there are no more enclosing `"` left.

You can assume that the string will be syntactically valid - At all stages, as long as the string starts and ends with `"`, all other backslashes and double quotes will be properly escaped, and only `"` and `\` will be escaped. The input string will not be `"` at any level of escaping. If the string starts and ends with `"`, the last `"` cannot be escaped, so e.g. `"abc\"` won't occur.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Testcases

```
e -> 1
"hello" -> 5
"\"\\" -> 2
a""b"c -> 6
"c\d+e -> 6
"\"\\\"Hello, World!\\\"\"" -> 13
"c\\\"d\"" -> 5
"\"\"" -> 0
"r\"\"" -> 3
"\"hello\"+" -> 8
"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Hello\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\"" -> 5
"\\\\\"" -> 3
[""] -> 4
```

Comment: Is it required to handle `[""]` or other valid JSON corrently?

Comment: [Effectively the opposite task](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230314/66833)

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, I'll add that as a testcase

Comment: `"the string will be syntactically valid"`, does that mean don't need to handle cases like `"\"`?

Comment: @DomHastings Yes, that's an invalid input.

Comment: What can we do about `'` vs `"`? Would it be ok to only handle inputs made with with `'`?

Comment: @DewiMorgan This is consistant with the other test cases such as `a""b"c -> 6`, you don't need to parse JSON, just be aware of it

Comment: @DewiMorgan There's no requirement to parse JSON at all, and indeed parsing the string as JSON will cause problems for your approach. `[""]` is a valid string that has not been escaped, so its length is simply 4.

Comment: @Jakav I'm going to only allow using `"`, because allowing `'` opens the door to backticks and various other types of quotes that deviate a bit from the intent of the challenge.

Comment: I downvoted this and changed my mind, but now I can't fix it anymore

Comment: Is the input `"` valid (and length 1)? What about `"\n"`? Is that length 2?

Comment: @NickKennedy Backslashes will only escape double quotes and other backslashes, so "\n" won't occur. Since it's a weird edgecase I'll say `"` won't occur

Comment: If we have a function `unescape`, then this challenge is asking to implement "Call `unescape` repeatedly until it no longer has an effect". Does anyone know if there is a name for the higher-order function "`(f, x) -> `start with `x` and call `f` repeatedly until it no longer has an effect"? Many algorithms can be implemented this way, for instance Dijkstra's is "Update nodes until no node can be updated" and Bubble sort is "Transpose adjacent pairs until no adjacent pairs need to be transposed".

Comment: What about a test case of `"\"foo\\\\""`?  That would evaluate to ``"foo\"` for a total of 6, correct, since the closing quote would be escaped and therefor not interpreted as ending the string even though it has an opening quote?

Comment: Looks like I messed up my formatting on the comment above.  I think the result should be `"foo\"` (6 characters).  Many of the current answers either fail on it or evaluate it to 4.

Comment: @Xcali That's something I should've dealt with in the sandbox. I don't want to invalidate all the existing answers, so I'll say that sort of thing won't occur, although I'll have to think about how to word it

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>/^".*"$/.test(x)?f(eval(x)):x.length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NTsMwEITvfoqwQordpk5LBapASW@IOwcuViXjbNIgExc7rcLTh9puqoq97My3P/MlT9Ip2x76RWcqHMe6GIoy3wGfwX3Oe3Q9Hdi2pniS@qzY88A1dk2/H18s/hxbizStXcq4RVm9thrffztFl1l67OtNwActFdJ8x2d0WySLMmH5d5MlriiV6ZzRyLVpaE0dY2xEv7AisEetDXjzSECAEEE/EAnwCcrrJwJKVHO8aL8j4M2fZcmHsbq680BAOFyt/fbZVxcQv0a9JGCvZu0HIV3APJDN9FzEmvpUMfQ/vOlwkxlYDPoD)

Trivial

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 47 bytes

```
+`(?=.*"$)(^"(?!$)|\\(.)|(?!^)"$)(?<=^".*)
$2
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsMgFET3nqIZLGgsLrpucNneoJuPJI1CC9KAdJm72xgVSmcz8x@fF/3n9Z7SUVzHpEZhBt2DS2EhTMflSiS0XLdtZcbmMljoXjJ@Zjolz/D0ISxgIBCBTcADM8NMTvkCCbf8cjrclxhclwEB@WVbbp@VxNpUpASFpqCS1i1F/Q9/ugr3E18) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
(?=.*"$)
```

Ensure the string ends with a `"` before making any replacements.

```
(^"(?!$)|\\(.)|(?!^)"$)
```

Replace a leading `"`, an escaped character or a trailing `"`, but not a lone `"`.

```
(?<=^".*)
```

Ensure that the string starts with a `"` before making any replacements.

```
$2
```

Unescape the character.

```
+`
```

Repeat until the string can't be unquoted further.

```
.
```

Get the length of the final string.

If `"` is excluded as being an unsupported input, then ten bytes can be saved by removing `(?!$)` and `(?!^)`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 11 bytes

```
ŒV.ị=”"ȦƲ¿L
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#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)

-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

### Explanation

```
ŒV.ị=”"ȦƲ¿L    Main Link
  ------Ʋ      Link Grouping (see below)
         ¿     While
  .ị               the first and last (index at 0.5)
       Ȧ           are all
    =”"            equal to "
ŒV             Evaluate (Python)
          L    Length
```

The footer runs all tests and prints `1` for any correct answers. `Ỵœṣ“ -> ”$€Ç=V}ɗ/€` means "split on newlines, split each string on substrings equal to `" -> "`, then for each pair, check that the result of the main link on the left side equals the right side evaluated (to convert to a number)".

For the link grouping, `Ʋ` combines four links into a monad, so you'd think we'd need to use `$` to capture the fifth, but since `”"Ȧ` would be an [LCC](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/beginners#leading-constant-chains) (a chain that begins with a nilad and only has monads and dyad-nilad/nilad-dyad pairs after it, so a chain with a constant result), it doesn't count that as a link and therefore keeps going one extra time. This is an important tip when understanding the link combining quicks as **all** of them do this and it is easy to miscount or misunderstand the grouping because it may be taking more links than you expect.

`ŒV.ị⁼⁾""Ʋ¿L` would also work where instead of `=”"Ȧ` to check that all are equal to `"`, we just check that it's equal to `['"', '"']`. This also makes the grouping a bit simpler because we don't have any potential LCCs so it just takes four links.

Comment: I’m clarifying, but I think this fails for the following input: `"`. It crashes rather than returning 1.

Comment: The OP has clarified that `"` won’t occur so you’re all good!

Comment: The code has 11 characters, but it is 19 bytes actually.

Comment: @KirillV.Lyadvinsky Jelly uses its own encoding so all 256 of the characters it uses occupy 1 byte each.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel ms365, 138 bytes

Assuming input in `A1`:

```
=LET(x,LAMBDA(f,s,IF(s<"",s,f(f,IFNA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(s,XMATCH("""*""",s,2)+1,LEN(s)-2),"\\","\"),"\""",""""),LEN(s))))),x(x,A1))
```

It's a recursive LAMBDA that will keep calling itself untill no more starting+leading double quotes.

---

## Google Spreadsheets, 107 bytes

Again, assuming input in `A1`, applying the same recursive logic with a few slight changes making use of the regex-functions:

```
=LET(x,LAMBDA(f,s,IF(REGEXMATCH(s,""".*"""),f(f,REGEXREPLACE(s,"^""|""$|\\(\\|"")","$1")),LEN(s))),x(x,A1))
```

Comment: Use `regexmatch(s,"^"".*""$")` to cover all test cases?

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
Ｗ¬∨⌕θ"⌕⮌Φθλ"≔⪫⁻⪪✂θ¹±¹¦¹\\¦\¦\θＩＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5BCsIwELz7ipDTBuqh555EEBGtYq@9hLq0C0tik1ifH5NWoTiX2d2ZYbYbtOus5hjfAzEKqG2Aq4MDmQeMhZCtlKoQ83rHCZ3HpHFAl1VW6mtJEDvvqTdwsmTgQubloXkyBWiYOsz2shA19joglClXztkEuQwrGlW1uTkyAfbaBzij6cMAYyqpYkx9OdQu@PEP8ojM9v@44vxu3E78AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ¬∨⌕θ"⌕⮌Φθλ"
```

Repeat while the string starts with `"` and ends with a different `"`...

```
≔⪫⁻⪪✂θ¹±¹¦¹\\¦\¦\θ
```

... remove those `"`s, split the string on `\\`, remove any remaining `\`s, then join the string on `\`, thus unquoting the string.

```
ＩＬθ
```

Output the length of the final string.

(Yes I could use eval to save 14 bytes but that's boring.)

If `"` is excluded as being an unsupported input, then two bytes can be saved by replacing `Φθλ` with `θ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.12/), <s>51</s> 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:f(eval(s))if'"'==s[-1:]==s[:1]else len(s)
```

Not complicated, but it works well.

**Explanation:**

Define a function f that takes an argument s:

```python
f=lambda s:
```

If the string begins and ends with `"`, return the value of the function with backslashes evaluated:

```python
f(eval(s))if'"'==s[-1:]==s[:1]
```

Otherwise, output the length of the string:

```python
len(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRodgqTSO1LDFHo1hTMzNNXUnd1rY4WtfQKhZEWxnGpuYUpyrkpOYB5f8XFGXmlWikaWTmFZSWaGhqav5XilGKiQHjGCQaBpQ8UnNy8tEFkWigdiUA)

Comment: Reversing your condition order `if'"'==s[0]==s[-1]` saves a byte.

Comment: Crash when result is 0

Comment: I’m clarifying, but I think this fails for the following input: `"`. It crashes rather than returning 1.

Comment: @NickKennedy I'd say `"` is invalid input but `""` is

Comment: The OP has clarified that `"` won’t occur so you’re all good!

Comment: Regarding l4m2's comment - you need to use `s[:1]` and `s[-1:]` to handle the case where the string becomes empty.

Comment: I already figured that out, but couldn't update my post until now.

Comment: `if'"'==s[-1:]==s[1]` is enough, for empty input `'"'==s[-1:]` is false thus `s[1]` not evaluated

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 45 bytes

```perl
s/\\(\\|")/$1/g while s/^"(.*)"$/$1/;$_=y///c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1Pi8JADMXv8ynGRw/@2TatbmVB1rMXzx6MitsOKgzb0i4sgp/dsZm2IuaSX17y8kpT2dTVpMNlNA6IFg0zD5lvGFGQ0En/ny/W6Jr2GEbjEQJRF8Hh@0pEmXOmcepE4WysLSBDqsBg9jxVR@AHmfBcIeN8YjqWG8ZKbB96U1Q2H4jA8MZkJtfNnHdC@7XlWKF6DjNZ@HTGxCtf/XNuq@99taHv4kvHS6bXuqAtsBP6vBfl36X4rV24TqM4iV1Y2gc)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 54 bytes

Handles the `"\"foo\\\""` testcase I proposed in the comments.  If that's not a valid test case, then the shorter version above will suffice.

```perl
s/\\(\\|")/$1/g while s/^"(.*[^\\])"$/$1/;say;$_=y///c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU1Na8JAEL3vr9g@cvArmaQ2Ugj23EvPPTgqNtmqsHRDIojQ395tZpMU6Vzmfcy8V5vG5r4lHb8ks4io6DDzhPkbU4oyOurr6WyNbmmHSTLb7Ji3U0RiFe3hVkT79Y2ISu9NF6EzhZOx1kFIrsBgDvhRHYAPlIJXCiVXczNguWG8yttCv7vGVg8iMMJjtpTrjleD0Kf2OFVo/shSjNDOmAfleQznfsY9Tl/6X7zbuOsM2lC0AbaCnqTg07lg/bj6cnZfrY/f8iTNUh/X9hc)

Comment: just 1 byte less [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU0xbsJAEOzvFc7IBWDstQFHiCjQ0lBTZAGBfYJIJ86y00Ti7Rzs2Y5QttmZ2Z2ZStcmdw0F8TIZhUQfLjx8NrTHIBkNEVKY0aoh5gHzDUOh56jWpV38ElHhnH4ag0zhoo2xEJIrMJg9nqgjcEIh@F2h4DLSHZYfxlps42Bra1O@icDwxmwq309edkKb2uJUof4jUzn4dkbklXkfzu30u5@29L/4svHS6bWu6AvYCZrdbfXzba@Nizd5kmapiyvzAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Your second version fails on `"\"foo\\\\\""`, which is a legal input for the first version. (Also it has a spare `say;` which you don't need.)

Comment: Oh, and is there any reason not to use `s/\\(.)/$1/g`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>91</s>90 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:f(s[1:-1].replace('\\"','"').replace(r'\\','\\'))if'"'==s[-1:]==s[0]else len(s)
```

because `eval` is evil :P, with inspiration from Jakav

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvBCkIhEEV/5TEbZ6AXSTvBff/wdGGlJEw@UVv09WZB8Wjg3gPnMvnZbms69h40u/v56qaqAtZFqlnaffGZ3cWjMAbEToCgnyrDDTWKKIYxaV2XWSr75sF6rn5in7BSzyWmhgFjyo@GRNTBgDGfmA2/ByfPvP7LDcc7vAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE, nice first answer! I think `.replace('\\"','"').replace(r'\\','\\')` can be shortened to just `.replace('\\','')` maybe? Not sure though.

Comment: @noodleman that was what I was initially thinking, but unfortunately it breaks with something like `"\\\\\""`

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense

Comment: `if'"'==s[-1:]==s[0]`

Answer (score 2):

## [QBASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 302 bytes

```
Q$ = CHR$(34): LINE INPUT T$: DO WHILE LEFT$(T$, 1) + RIGHT$(T$, 1) = Q$ + Q$: U$ = MID$(T$, 2, LEN(T$) - 2): T$ = "": C$ = "": FOR J = 1 TO LEN(U$): C$ = C$ + MID$(U$, J, 1): B = -(C$ <> "\"): T$ = T$ + RIGHT$(C$, B * ((INSTR("\\" + Q$, C$) > 0) + 2)): C$ = LEFT$(C$, 1 - B): NEXT: LOOP: PRINT LEN(T$)
```

A bit of nostalgia...

**Explanation:**

```
'Set quote mark because QBASIC doesn't have string escaping 
'then get string
Q$ = CHR$(34)
LINE INPUT T$
'Process the string while it starts and ends with quotes
DO WHILE LEFT$(T$, 1) + RIGHT$(T$, 1) = Q$ + Q$
    'Strip enclosing quotes, assign to a temporary variable,
    'prepare to rebuild the original string,
    'and prepare to track current character(s)
    U$ = MID$(T$, 2, LEN(T$) - 2)
    T$ = ""
    C$ = ""
    'Process string character by character.
    FOR J = 1 TO LEN(U$)
        'Add current character to current status
        C$ = C$ + MID$(U$, J, 1)
        'QBASIC boolean ops return -1 for true, 0 for false,
        'so set B to 0 if current character is an escape char, to 1 otherwise.
        B = -(C$ <> "\")
        'Add current character to string if not an escape char,
        'de-escaping if appropriate
        T$ = T$ + RIGHT$(C$, B * ((INSTR("\\" + Q$, C$) > 0) + 2))
       'Clear current character unless it's an escape char
        C$ = LEFT$(C$, 1 - B)
    NEXT
LOOP
PRINT LEN(T$)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ¬'"Qi.E]g
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRDa9SVAjP1XGPT//9XUlKKVlKKBVIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/3NTDq1RVwrM1HOtrU3/r/M/lUspIzUnJ1@JSylGKSZGiStRSSlJKZlLKTkmRTsVIhij5AFSoqMQnl@Uk6IIEohRUgIpAbJSwEyoSBGUjoEYGqOkrQQzIgYCYDQMQIxGF0SioQaCuUpc0UpKsVxKAA). (Note: in the single TIO, the input is wrapped within `"""`-quotes to always have a string input.)

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ         # Loop until the result no longer changes:
 ¬        #  Push its first character (without popping the string)
  '"Qi   '#  If it's a double quote:
      .E  #   Evaluate the string as Elixir code
]         # Close both the if-statement and changes-loop
 g        # Pop and push the length of the reduced string
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
L?&b&qhbNqebNyvblbyw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38deLUmtMCPJrzA1ya@yLCknqbL8/3@lGKWYGDCOQaJhQMkjNScnH10QiQZqVwIA)

Same approach as Jakav's Python solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `l`, 70 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.75 bytes

```
Sλh\"=ßE;Ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#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)

Bitstring:

```
0110001110110011010000001101101101100000011010011000101001000111010000
```

Port of 05ab1e except i had to add a "stringify" at the start for the final case